# Как правильно использовать микроразметку для скрываемых блоков?

Tags: html, seo, microdata

Правила [микроразметки](http://schema.org) гласят, что необходимо размечать контент, который видим на странице, и нельзя ее применять, если контент скрыт. Имеется следующая проблема: на странице товара имеется два заголовка, и в зависимости от ширины экрана, отображается либо один, либо другой. Аналогичная ситуация с блоком цены: в зависимости от ширины, отображается либо блок с ценой над фото, либо под ним.

Судя по правилам гугла и Schema я не могу использовать микроразметку на скрываемых элементах (display: none). Возможно ли решить вопрос, сохраняя текущий способ отображения контента?

Upd. Скрытие/показ блоков и логика поведения реализована через CSS, js нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ на просторах [SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903526/is-it-ok-to-hide-microdata-with-css)

Сайт schema.org содержит вариант микроразметки, который может вам подойти:
http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_missing
Они предлагают использовать тег *meta* с аттрибутом *content* для разметки элементов, которые "проблематично разметить ввиду способа их отображения на странице".
Надеюсь, помог.